# Calculate: $\iint_{D}\cos\left(\frac{x+2y}{-x+y}\right)dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Let D be the triangle region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having vertices $(0,0), (-2,4), (-3,3).$ Calculate: $$\iint_{D}\cos\left(\frac{x+2y}{-x+y}\right)dx\,dy$$

I use change variable $x+2y=u$, $-x+y=v$. Finally, it leads to calculate: $\int\limits_0^6\int\limits_{\frac1{3}u}^{\frac2{3}u}\frac13\cos(\dfrac{u}{v})dudv$. I cannot finish with this final step. Could you please help me?

Comment: You can't have $u$ be the dummy variable *and*  the bounds of the inner integral.

Comment: I just corrected it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user288742: That's correct. So, I have no idea what I should continue to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=(u+v)/2$ and $y=(u-v)/2$. This takes the region to the *right triangle* (that's the real point of this substitution) with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,-6)$ and $(2,-6)$ in the $uv$-plane. The Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2}$. This is just the typical substitution taking an ugly triangle to something more tractable (namely a right triangle).

Choosing the order in which we integrate correctly (we can do that here): $$\iint_{D}\cos\left(\frac{x+2y}{-x+y}\right)\,dx\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-6}^{0}\int_{0}^{-v/3}\cos\left(\frac{v-3 u}{2 v}\right)\,du \,dv\ldotp$$

This is $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-6}^{0}\frac{2}{3} v \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sin (1)\right)\,dv=6 \left(\sin (1)-\sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. How do you come up with the idea of changing variables like that?

Comment: @user52523 The region $D$ was ugly so I bet that integrating over $\mathbf{G}(D)$ where $\mathbf{G}(x,y)=(u,v)=(x+y,x-y)$ would make it easier because $\mathbf{G}$ realigns the triangle's non-hypotenuse edges with the coordinate axes. Fortuitously, it happened to be the case that the argument of the cosine became $\frac{v-3u}{2v}$ and because I've made the region nice, I can easily take the order of integration to be wrt $u$ and then wrt $v$ (idk an elementary antiderivative of $\cos(1/z)$). After that, everything fell together and made the integral doable.

Comment: Frankly, your method should work as well. You've just got the bounds on the integral incorrect. You're integrating wrt to $u$ with bounds involving the variable $u$. (Also your region isn't particularly nice.) I generally find it easier to approach these problems by visualizing how the region transforms before I make a change of variable, hence, why I chose $u$ and $v$ as I did.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had the same idea with you but I don't know how to change variable as you did.

Comment: I very neatly hid away the mess of it—sort of like letting something be less than $\varepsilon/5$ from the get-go. The actual work involved is in noticing that $D$ is a right triangle whose legs are not aligned with the axes. However, the legs of interest lie along the lines $x-y=6$ and $x+y=0$. This suggests letting $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. I massaged that into $x=...$ and $y=...$ without comment. You'll get better at it with practice!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to explain for me.